# No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

When I add an autowire into my controller I get the following exception:

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I am not sure how to solve this any suggestions please?
I was wondering whether or not it was something to do with my component scan in the application context?
My controller:

```
package com.projectShaun.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.projectShaun.service.AccountService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        modelAndView.addObject("greeting", "Welcome to projectShaun!");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd" >

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.projectShaun" />

  <tx:annotation-driven/>

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectshaun" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
     <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.projectShaun.model.Account</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop 
         key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
  </bean>
</beans>
```

DefaultServlet-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.projectShaun" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

AccountService:

```
package com.projectShaun.service;

import com.projectShaun.model.Account;

public interface AccountService {

    void persistAccount(Account account);

}
```

HomeController:

```
package com.projectShaun.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.projectShaun.service.AccountService;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        modelAndView.addObject("greeting", "Welcome to projectShaun!");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

accountServiceImpl:

```
package com.projectShaun.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.projectShaun.dao.AccountDao;
import com.projectShaun.model.Account;

@Service("accountService")
@Transactional
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountDao accountDao;

    public void persistAccount(Account account) {
        accountDao.persistAccount(account);
    }

}
```

Web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You added <context:component-scan base-package="com.projectShaun" /> in both ApplicationContext.xml and DefaultServlet-servlet.xml.So remove from the DefaultServlet-servlet.xml.May this solve your problem

Comment: This didnt work it gave a 404. I also tried it the other way round, taking it out of applicationContext.

Comment: @Shaun where is the code for `AccountService ` or how you are creating it as a component.

Comment: @ankur-singhal i have updated my question and added in AccountService

Comment: @Shaun `AccountService ` is not a spring component, i think you have to make it as a bean using `@Named`  or `@Component`

Comment: @ankur-singhal i have added the following: @Component("accountService")
public interface AccountService {

Comment: Also add the implementation class of AccountService interface.
Also can you check that if @Autowired AccountService accountService; remove from the controller , application runs or not ?

Comment: Your <context:component-scan base-package="com.projectShaun" /> should this not be com.projectShaun.controller and .service etc? Otherwise your referencing your project and not a package?

Comment: @Mahesh I have added accountServiceImpl and the app runs when i remove AccountService accountService; remove from the controller.

Comment: Please provide the web.xml file

Comment: Rename DefaultServlet-servlet.xml to dispatcher-servlet.xml .And remove the <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.projectShaun" />.

Also add <mvc:annotation-driven /> in ApplicationContext.xml.

Comment: Also where is servlet-context ? I think there is lots of xml files that creating lots of confusion.

Comment: @Mahesh hi mahesh, really sorry, i accidently added a different web.xml from a different project. i have updated the code above. Thanks and sorry about that. I haven't carried out any of the other changes yet, do these still apply?

Comment: Please see my answer and configure your project.I am using the below configuration in all my projects

Comment: @Mahesh I think this has worked, but i am not being allowed access to the page i am trying to access through the controller. I am getting the following error: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/projectShaun/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'

Comment: @Mahesh does this mean my applicationContext needs to be inside of WEB-INF?

Comment: All xml files need to be in WEB-INF folder.WEB-INF provides security that its files not acceded outside.

Comment: Also add your jsp pages in WEB-INF/jsp/ folder

Comment: @Mahesh I have done all of this and i am still getting the error to do with no mapping found

Comment: do you have welcome.jsp in WEB-INF/jsp folder ??

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of xml file that creating lots of confusion.First configure the simple mvc then add security and filter .So for simple mvc your web.xml be looks like below

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.projectShaun" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```